# Views not performing segue

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a collection of views and I want to make that when they are tapped, it will perform the same segue. and no view performs any segue.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var categoryViews: [UIView]!


let tapGesture = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.move(tap:)))
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for category in (0..<categoryViews.count) {
        categoryViews[category].addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        categoryViews[category].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@objc func move(tap: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Animals", sender: nil)
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single instance of `UITapGestureRecognizer` can be added to a single view.

In your code, since you're using a single instance of `UITapGestureRecognizer` for each view, the `tapGesture` will be added only to the last `view` in `categoryViews` `array`.

You need to create different `UITapGestureRecognizer` instance for each `view` in `categoryViews`, i.e.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var categoryViews: [UIView]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        categoryViews.forEach {
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(move(tap:)))
            $0.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }

    @objc func move(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Animals", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tapGesture = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.move(tap:)))
```

Your `let tapGesture` is an instance property declaration, and what follows the equal sign is its initializer. But you can't speak of `self` in an instance property initializer; there is no instance yet. So `self` here is taken to be the *class*. Thus, your tap gesture recognizer "works", but the `move` message is not sent to your ViewController instance; in effect, it is sent into empty space.

To fix this, you can initialize `tapGesture` at a time when `self` does exist. For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tapGesture : UIGestureRecognizer!
    func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.move(tap:)))
```